# WPF WebBrowser not display page

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a WPF `UserControl` with a `WebBrowser`. It loads page after running but not displaying the loaded page.

```
<UserControl x:Class="PsyboInventory.Tiles.About.AboutTile"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser x:Name="browser" Height="253" Margin="300,96,36,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

On cs code

```
public AboutTile()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    try
    {
        browser.Loaded += delegate
        {
            browser.Navigate("http://www.google.fi/");
        };
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Is this really all the code you have in the `UserControl`'s XAML? Where is `lblCopy` defined? Also can you update your post with the part where you use the `AboutTile`? I'm asking because I tried this example (without the `lblCopy`) and it worked fine for me (except for the two script errors on the page)

Comment: Its not an error iam included a Label in my usercontroll.Its runing no syntax error

Comment: If you try it this way without the `Loaded` handler and the `Margin`/`Height`, do you see anything? `<WebBrowser x:Name="browser" Source="http://www.google.fi/" />`

Comment: Iam tried it but page loaded but not visible

Comment: Is there a specific reason for the empty `catch` block?